# Blob trigger does not pick up files from part of the path pattern

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I have a function with a blob trigger configured to run based on a certain path pattern.
e.g. `sites/{site}/{system}/logs/{year}/{month}/{day}/myfile.txt`

The problem is that the function works only on some folders of the pattern. In other words, the function runs for :
sites/site1/**01**/logs/2022/02/10/myfile.txt, but does not trigger for
sites/site1/**02**/logs/2022/02/10/myfile.txt

In the application insights logs I saw an exception:
"The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob." but I am not sure if that is related.

What could be the reason for a blob trigger to pick up files only from certain parts of its pattern? How can this be fixed?

Thanks